# A Regex replace case in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to replace all numbers in a `<number></number>` element as `xxx` if the number length is 15 or 16.

for example `<number>1234567812345678</number>` ->  `<number>xxx</number>`

I did something like below but it replace the numbers even if their' length is bigger than 16. How to prevent this case ?

```
string test = "<number>1234567812345678</number><number>12345671234567</number><number>1234567123456712345678</number>";

test = Regex.Replace(test, @"([\d]{15,16})", "xxx");
```

Unwanted output

```
<number>xxx</number><number>12345671234567</number><number>xxx345678</number>
```

Wanted output

```
 <number>xxx</number><number>12345671234567</number><number>1234567123456712345678</number>
```

Comment: You want to specify that it is preceded by something that is not a digit and followed by something that is not a digit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string test = "<number>1234567812345678</number><number>12345671234567</number><number>1234567123456712345678</number>";

test = Regex.Replace(test, @"(?<=>)\d{15,16}(?=<)", "xxx");
```

This makes sure that the number is preceded by a `>` and followed by a `<`, using [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: This is more exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much. I will mark it when I can.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify that the numbers should be preceded by `<number>` and followed by `</number>`. You can do it like this:

```
test = Regex.Replace(test, @"(?<=<number>)([\d]{15,16})(?=</number>)", "xxx");
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex by default will replace substrings unless you tell it how the string is supposed to end.  You need to surround your [\d]{15,16} with matchers against the  tag like this:

```
Regex.Replace(test, @"<number>[\d]{15,16}</number>", @"<number>xxx</number>");
```